# Determining Quadratic Variation for a Stochastic Process

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Define $X_t=aW_t+bt$ where $W_t$ is a brownian motion and $a,b$ are constants.  Determine the quadratic variation for $X_t$, i.e. $lim_{P \to 0} \sum_{i=1}^{n} |X_{t_{i}}-X_{t_{i-1}}|^2$ where $P$ partitions the interval $[0,t]$.

Substitution the formula for $X_t$ into the the equation for quadratic variation we have $lim_{P \to 0} \sum_{i=1}^{n} |X_{t_{i}}-X_{t_{i-1}}|^2=lim_{P \to 0} \sum_{i=1}^{n} |(aW_{t_i}+bt_{i})-(aW_{t_{i-1}}+bt_{i-1})|^2=lim_{P \to 0} \sum_{i=1}^{n} |a(W_{t_i}-W_{t_{i-1}})+b(t_{i}-t_{i-1})|^2$.

I'm not entirely sure how to carry on from here.

Comment: Are you familiar with quadratic *co*variation? It can simplify calculations here.

Comment: @Jason Can you provide details?  I am not sure I know what you mean.